# how to rearrange terms in Coq using plus communtativity and associativity?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I have a general question about how to rearrange terms in Coq. For example, if we have a term `m + p + n + p`, humans can quickly re-arrange the terms to something like `m + n + p + p` (implicitly using plus_comm and plus_assoc). How do we do this efficiently in Coq?

For a (silly) example,

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Plus.
Require Import Coq.Setoids.Setoid.

Theorem plus_comm_test: forall n m p: nat,
  m + p + (n + p) = m + n + 2 * p.
Proof. intros. rewrite plus_assoc. simpl. rewrite <- plus_n_O.
```

Now, we have

```
1 subgoals
...
______________________________________(1/1)
m + p + n + p = m + n + (p + p)
```

My question is:

How do I rewrite the LHS to `m + n + p + p` effectively?

I tried to use `rewrite plus_comm at 2`, but it gives an error `Nothing to rewrite.` Simply using rewrite `plus_comm` changes the LHS to `p + m + n + p`.

Any suggestions on effective rewrites are also welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Arthur says sometimes `omega` is not enough, but I sometimes use it for simple steps like this.

```
Require Import Omega.
Theorem test: forall a b c:nat, a + b + 2 * c = c + b + a + c.
  intros.
  replace (c + b + a) with (a + b + c) by omega.
  replace (a + b + c + c) with (a + b + (c + c)) by omega.
  replace (c + c) with (2 * c) by omega.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

This is a silly example, because `omega` would have solved it all in one go, but sometimes you want to rewrite things inside functions that `omega` can't reach into without a little help...

Answer (score 2):

In this particular case (linear arithmetic over the integers), you can just use the `omega` tactic:

```
Require Import Omega.

Theorem plus_comm_test: forall n m p: nat,
  m + p + (n + p) = m + n + 2 * p.
Proof. intros; omega. Qed.
```

However, there are situations where `omega` is not enough. In those cases, the standard `rewrite` tactic is not very convenient. The [Ssreflect](http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr/) library comes with its own version of the `rewrite` tactic, that works much better for tasks such as rewriting on sub-terms of your goal. For instance:

```
Require Import Ssreflect.ssreflect Ssreflect.ssrfun Ssreflect.ssrbool.
Require Import Ssreflect.ssrnat.

Theorem plus_comm_test: forall n m p: nat,
  m + p + (n + p) = m + n + 2 * p.
Proof.
move=> n m p.
by rewrite -addnA [p + _]addnC -[_ + p]addnA addnn -mul2n addnA.
Qed.
```

The annotations in square brackets, such as `[p + _]`, provide patterns that help the `rewrite` tactic figure out where to act. The `addn*` lemmas and friends are Ssreflect's own version of the standard arithmetic results over the natural numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what I showed is part of a larger proof on `nat`. The `m+p+n+p` part is enclosed in something else. Also, I am trying to learn how Coq works. Do you know of a more primitive Coq way to do this without involving external libraries?

Comment: I wish I did... I personally could never figure out how to learn the syntax for all the features of `rewrite` in standard Coq. I _believe_ that there could be a bug that makes selection occurrence behave incorrectly when the `Setoid` library is used, but I am not sure. In any case, you can always explicitly supply the parameters to your lemmas, which helps avoiding ambiguities in some cases, e.g. `rewrite <- (plus_assoc m p)`.

Comment: You can also use `assert` to prove the equation that you want separately using `omega`, and then rewrite with it directly.

Comment: I seem to remember that setoid_rewrite would perform more in the way I intend than rewrite, especially when using `at <n>` to rewrite the n-th occurence. This is definitely a pain in Coq.

Answer (score 0):

The `ring` tactic is able to prove equality of these rearrangements.

Using your example:

```
Require Import ZArith.
Open Scope Z_scope.

(* Both "ring" and "omega" can prove this. *)
Theorem plus_comm_test : forall n m p : Z,
  m + p + (n + p) = m + n + 2 * p.
Proof.
  intros.
  ring.
Qed.
```

`ring` works on the integers, but I don't think it works on the natural numbers.

However, `ring` is able to prove some identities that `omega` cannot prove.  (The [docs](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/omega.html) say, "Multiplication is handled by omega but only goals where at least one of the two multiplicands of products is a constant are solvable. This is the restriction meant by "Presburger arithmetic".")

For example:

```
(* "ring" can prove this but "omega" cannot. *)
Theorem rearrange_test : forall a b c : Z,
  a * (b + c) = c*a + b*a.
Proof.
  intros.
  ring.
Qed.
```