# To which subterms can we apply a lemma?

Tags: coq

Suppose we have the goal

```
a + b + c + d = a + c + b + d
```

where `a, b, c, d: nat` and the lemma `plus_comm` from `Arith`:

```
plus_comm
     : forall n m : nat, n + m = m + n
```

It is possible to do

- `rewrite plus_comm.`  to obtain `d + (a + b + c) = a + c + b + d` and
- `rewrite (plus_comm a b).` to obtain `b + a + c + d = a + c + b + d`.

But doing `rewrite (plus_comm b c)` or `rewrite (plus_comm c d)` will throw an error similar to

```
Found no subterm matching "b + c" in the current goal.
```

**Question.**
Why is this the case, and what can we do to rewrite `b + c` as `c + b` in the goal?

---

**Edit.**
To rewrite `b + c` as `c + b` we can do

```
rewrite (plus_assoc_reverse a).
rewrite (plus_comm b c).
rewrite plus_assoc.
```

To prove the lemma using `reflexivity.`
Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `+` operator in Coq is left associative, so terms like `a + b + c + d` are actually `((a + b) + c) + d` in disguise. This should answer why `plus_comm` doesn't do what you expect.

To solve these types of goals you need to apply a series of lemmas as you've found out. This can often be tedious, so there are some tactics available to solve these, like `omega` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32982507/how-to-rearrange-terms-in-coq-using-plus-communtativity-and-associativity) question).

Answer (score 4):

In this case, if you want to avoid having to know all the theorems by heart, you can often write:

`ring`

This command (also called a tactic), is available as soon as you have loaded the `Arith` library.  It is specialized to proving equalities where the two terms are the same modulo associativity, commutativity of addition and multiplication, and distributivity of multiplication over addition.  If you are using the type of integers `Z`, you can also include subtraction.

The tactic `omega` that has been suggested in another answer will do the trick, but only for formulas that contain limited forms of multiplication.  As a side note, `omega` will be retired in future versions of Coq, it will be replaced by a tactic named `lia` (which stands for linear integer arithmetic).