# How to rearrange newly defined associative terms in Coq?

Tags: coq, theorem-proving, coq-tactic, formal-verification, associativity

I wonder what is the most elegant way of rearranging associative terms in Coq. I think it is a well-defined problem for some existing operators, such as [plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32982507/how-to-rearrange-terms-in-coq-using-plus-communtativity-and-associativity).

I have defined new associative operater and operands with corresponding types. In short, an associative lemma states that

`Lemma assoc: forall A B C: sometype, A # (B # C) = A # B # C`

Surely, all chains organized in the same order are equal no matter how to put the brackets. e.g.

`A # B # C # D # E = (A # B) # (C # (D # E)) = (A # (B # (C # (D # E))))`

I know one can use `repeat rewrite assoc.` or `repeat rewrite <- assoc.`to achieve LHS or RHS from the middle expression. Now I want to apply a lemma about `(B # C)`. How can I quickly rewrite the expression to something like,

`A # (B # C) # D # E`

One solution is to use `replace ... with ... by now rewrite assoc.` However, it can be tedious when the expressions are getting longer. Is there any other effective way of rearranging terms/bracket? Is the `aac-tactics` library helpful for the problem? I cannot find a tutorial for using `aac` over the customized operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes [AAC-Tactics](https://github.com/coq-community/aac-tactics) is the recommended tactic for such problems. It provides an extensible tactic for associative and commutative rewriting. The tutorial is here (https://github.com/coq-community/aac-tactics/blob/master/theories/Tutorial.v).

AAC-Tactics is included in [Coq Platform](https://github.com/coq/platform), so you can expect long term support for it.